# Powershell Read File, Search for Pattern Delete the Pattern, Write out to same or new file

Tags: powershell

I am extremely new to Powershell and I have a task that I need to perform at work for a project. Here is the question. I have a multiple files but once the code works for one I can run them as a batch.
The file content looks like this:

```
AAA0000XYZZ
BBB0001H0351
CXXXXX  ABCUABSS    22/11/1990
YYY0001H035100001
ZZZ0000XYZZ
```

This is the code I've written so far

```
$pattern = "BBB*H0351(.*?)YYY*H0351"
PS F:\Practice_Codes> $data = get-content PS1.txt
PS F:\Practice_Codes> $Result = $Data -replace $pattern,""
PS F:\Practice_Codes> $Result
```

The code doesnt give out any errors but it doesnt replace the pattern from the text either.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance. Some more detail if it is required. Powershell Version

```
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.431
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.431
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: $data is an array of (string) lines in this case. Try something like this: $result = $data |foreach {$_ -replace $pattern,""}

Comment: The asterisk in a RegEx is not a wildcard but a `Quantifier for the previous char/group — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)` In your case `BBB*` it would match the last `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess what you are after.
See an explanation of the REgEx used on https://regex101.com/r/qen2VS/1

**Due to increasing requirements we need a better single RegEx**
that uses [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\10\SO_50777935.ps1
$Text=@"
AAA0000XYZZ
BBB0001H0351
CXXXXX  ABCUABSS    22/11/1990
YYY0001H03510000001
ZZZ0000XYZZ
AAA0001XYZZ
BBB0001H9561
CXXXXX  ABCUABSS    22/11/1990
YYY0001H95610000001
ZZZ0001XYZZ
"@

$Pattern ="(?s)BBB\d+(H0351|H9561).*?YYY\d+\1\d+\r?\n"

$text -replace $pattern
```

---

```
AAA0000XYZZ
ZZZ0000XYZZ
AAA0001XYZZ
ZZZ0001XYZZ
```

The `(?S)`= single line changes the RegEx behaviour to also match cr/lf
**Alternation** `(H0351|H9561)` matches either `H0351` or `H9561`
**Backreference** `\1` matches again the result found with `(H0351|H9561)`

A script replacing pattern in all *.txt files in current folder:

```
$Pattern ="(?s)BBB\d+(H0351|H9561).*?YYY\d+\1\d+\r?\n"
ForEach($File in (Get-ChildItem *.txt -File)){
    (Get-Content $File -Raw) -Replace $Pattern | Set-Content $File
}
```

Comment: If this is what's intended, be sure to use `get-content -raw` to read the data. This will read the file contents as a single string. Without `-raw`, `get-content` will return an array of strings.

Comment: Added a small script that iterates all `*.txt` files in the current folder. BTW If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @Bruce Payette Correct the -raw at the end of the file path did the trick. Also a follow up question the YYY line has 7 digits at the end 0000001. The 1 represents the number of records between the BBB line and the YYY line. So it can be variable. How do I include the 7 digits after the H0351 in the pattern?

Comment: You shouldn't need to define the digits outside of the match which ends with `H0351` so they aren't replaced.

Comment: But I want to replace them so I only have AAA and ZZZ. Right now I have to manually go and erase the next 7 characters left after the H0351 in the YYY line.

Comment: Then simply append `\d{7}` to the pattern what means another 7 digits. I'll change itabove

Comment: Awesome. And that script for iterating all files in the folder. Its beautiful. And sorry I'm not able to upvote right now since I only have 5 reputation. But I accepted the answer. Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: @LotPings How do I get rid of that extra empty line thats left after removing the pattern from the file?

Comment: See above changed pattern with an addiotional `\r?\n`

Comment: Hey @LotPings sorry for asking so many follow up question. So I ran the batch script too it worked nicely. I have 2 things If I have 2 patterns instead of 1 how do I introduce it in the loop. I wrote this but this gave me an error: 
$Pattern ="(?s)BBB\d+H0351(.*?)YYY\d+H0351\d{5}\r?\n"
$Pattern1 ="(?s)BBB\d+H9561(.*?)YYY\d+H9561\d{5}\r?\n"
ForEach($File in (Get-ChildItem *.txt -File)){
    $File1 = (Get-Content $File -Raw) -Replace $Pattern 
    $File1 -Replace $Pattern1 | Set-Content $File1
}
Can I save this file in a new path instead of overwriting?

Comment: There are several  flaws with your approach. You **could** use several patterns, but then only apppend after the the first replace `-replace $Pattern -replace $Pattern1` There is a much better solution with only one enhanced RegEx, see changed answer. BTW **not** posting a **new** question stole my chance to gain more reputation  and your chance getting more attention and possibly better answers from others.